# How to check whether value in dataframe A appears in dataframe B and return a binary value if true?

Tags: r, dplyr

I need some dplyr merging 101 help, please. I have merged my Main List of schools and their attributes (see Table A. below) with the State Database (Table B.). Some of the school names are written differently in my database and therefore while the merge works for many schools, the attributes (like 'Type' in Table A) cannot be found in instances where the name is incorrect in my A. Main List. The solution that I have thought of is to create a variable within A. called, "Found in state database" and assign it binary values accordingly. If I get a "0", then I know to go in manually and clean up the school name.

How can I reference both 2 dfs at once and create the variable that I have described? Or is there something easier that I haven't thought of. Thanks in advance.

A. Main List

| School | Type | Found in state database |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple ES | Charter | 0 |
| Bolton High | District | 1 |
| Bruce Elementary | District | 0 |

B. State Database

| School | Exceeded Expectations |
| --- | --- |
| Apple Elementary | 23% |
| Bolton High | 82% |
| Bruce ES | 44% |

Comment: Please provide some code example.

Comment: I think you're looking for string similarity, look at the `stringdist` package or the `utils::adist` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not find which values are not found in the other with a logical operation on unique values:

```
 vals <- unique( Main_list$School )
 vals[ ! vals %in% unique(State_Database$School) ] #returns vector of school names
```

There are also approximate merges. Install the `fuzzyjoin` package.